# Validation failed for one or more entities. User Name is already taken?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I have two tables: `Tasks` and `Users` (`ApplicationUser`), there is a many to many relationship between them, I'm using the pre-defined table Users of Microsoft Identity,
When I update an existing `Task` and assign new users to it:

```
  var taskToUpdate = context.Tasks.Find(taskVM.Id);
        context.Entry(taskToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        taskToUpdate.Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
        foreach (var user in taskVM._Users)
        {
            var userDB = context.Users.Find(user.Id);
            context.Entry(userDB).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            taskToUpdate.Users.Add(user);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
```

But when `SaveChanges` is called I got this error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

in EntityValidationErrors:

ErrorMessage = "User name Sohaib is already taken."
PropertyName User

Answer (score 0):

when calling the `.Users.Add` method EF assumes you are adding new entities thus creating the new User record and throwing the exception 
possible solution is

```
var taskToUpdate = context.Tasks.Find(taskVM.Id);
taskToUpdate.Users = taskVM.Users;
context.SaveChanges();
```